# Scala: argument to map is a function OR function invocation

Tags: scala, mapper

```
Array("hi","there").map(println)
Array("hi","there").map(s => println(s))
Array("hi","there").map(println(_))
```

Each of the above statements yields the same output though in the first 2 argument to map is a function object whereas in the last one it is function invocations.

How is **map** able to handle both?

Signature of **map** in **TraversableLike** class is like this:

```
def map[B, That](f: scala.Function1[A, B])(implicit bf: scala.collection.generic.CanBuildFrom[Repr, B, That]) : That = { /* compiled code */ }
```

Answer (score 2):

> How is map able to handle both?

It is able to handle both because the compiler created a [*method value*](http://scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.11/06-expressions.html#method-values) for `map` by performing [*eta-expansion*](http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.11/06-expressions.html#eta-expansion) on the `println`. There is a distinction in Scala between methods and functions, where the former doesn't hold any value, which makes the compiler need to go the extra mile to make it work.

The compiler after eta-expansion actually emits:

```
Array("hi","there").map(s => println(s))
```

Matching your second example. The actual code is more verbose, but means the same:

```
scala.this.Predef.refArrayOps[String](
  scala.Array.apply[String]("hi", "there")(
  (ClassTag.apply[String](classOf[java.lang.String]): scala.reflect.ClassTag[String])))
  .map[Unit, Any]({((x: Any) => scala.this.Predef.println(x))
  })(scala.this.Array.canBuildFrom[Unit]((ClassTag.Unit: scala.reflect.ClassTag[Unit])));
```

As @slouc said in the comments, the third example using the placeholder syntax is desugered into `s => println(s)`, which makes it an equivalent to your second example.

As a complete not so important side note, since `println` returns `Unit`, `Array.foreach` would be more suitable here:

```
Array("hi","there").foreach(println)
```

Comment: I would just add that both 1st and 3rd case are transformed into the 2nd one, but by different mechanisms; first one is eta-expansion as Yuval explained, while third one is simple compiler de-sugaring (`println(_)` and `s => println(s)` are literally the same thing, former being the short form of the latter). Compiler would not be able to fit the 1st example into definition of map without eta-expansion since type of `def foo = println` is `Unit`, not `(String) => Unit`. On the other hand, `def foo = println(_)` is of type `(String) => Unit` and hence 2nd and 3rd work out-of-the-box.

Comment: @slouc Added to the answer!